# Как при нажатии в Bottom Navigation View на открытую вкладку сделать так, чтобы она не открывалась повторно?

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

В Bottom Navigation View есть две вкладки. При нажатии каждой вкладки открывается определенный fragment. Как при нажатии в Bottom Navigation View на открытую вкладку сделать так, чтобы она не открывалась повторно(если она уже открыта)?

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_nav);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.action_one:
                        fragment = new OneFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_two:
                        fragment = new TwoFragment();
                        break;
}
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Запомнить, какая вкладка открыта и если выбрана она же, то игнорировать. Покажите код, как вы обрабатываете клики по вкладкам и открываете их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запомните, какая вкладка была открыта и если выбрана она же, то игнорируйте клик:

```
private int currentPageId = -1;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if (currentPageId == item.getItemId()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                currentPageId = item.getItemId();
                ...
                // Do usual navigation
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```